# Bootstrap card header gets overlapped only in Safari browsers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, safari

We have this problem where, we are building a div that contains a card header, and under it, it contains a div that is a list of items, now on PC and other phones it shows like this just fine:

[image]

However, on safari browsers, this card header is overlapped by the list:

[image]

It can be seen a bit, but barely.

We are not sure why this happens, and since we can't inspect element on neither an iPhone or an iPad (We assume it's a safari problem), and we don't have a mac either, we are not sure why this happens.

This is the html of this section:

```html
<div class="tab-pane active" id="form_cliente_datos_historias_tab" role="tabpanel" style="flex-flow: column; flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto;">
 <div class="list-group" style="padding-top: 0rem; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" id="form_cliente_datos_historias_tab_a">                        
  <form method="POST" id="form_cliente_datos_historias" role="form" class="is-readonly">                        
  </form>                    

  <div class="btn-group card-header justify-content-between">
   <h5><span class="align-middle">Cuadros Clínicos</span></h5>
   <div class="navbar-form"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_nuevo_cuadro_tab">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="list_cuadros_tab">
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--An example of a generated list from our DB -->
 <div class="list-group" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;" id="form_cliente_datos_historias_tab_aa">
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" id="CC801" data-id="801">
 <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
  <h5 class="mb-1">testtesttesttestasdasdasd</h5>
  <small class="text-muted">29/09/2019 18:23</small>
  </div>
  <p class="mb-1">123123123</p>
  <small>123123</small><br>
 </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" id="CC799" data-id="799"><div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
  <h5 class="mb-1">asasdasdasd123123123</h5>
  <small class="text-muted">29/09/2019 18:13</small>
  </div>
  <p class="mb-1">asdasdasdasd</p>
  <small>asdasdasdasd</small><br>
 </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" id="CC796" data-id="796"><div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
  <h5 class="mb-1">awdawdawd</h5>
  <small class="text-muted">29/09/2019 18:11</small>
  </div>
  <p class="mb-1">awdawdawd</p>
  <small>awdawd</small><br>
 </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" id="CC797" data-id="797"><div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
  <h5 class="mb-1">awdawdawd</h5>
  <small class="text-muted">29/09/2019 18:11</small>
  </div>
  <p class="mb-1">awdawdawd</p>
  <small>awdawd</small><br>
 </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Seyren/Lwakg8xd/

Hopefully i provided everything possible for this question, if there's anything else i can provide, please let me know

This is something really weird that i'm not sure how to fix, hopefully someone here knows why this might be

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its working fine in iphones as well

Comment: Do you mind trying on this version? It has way more items added to the list, apparently, the more items the list has, the more it shrinks into the header. https://jsfiddle.net/Seyren/Lwakg8xd/2/

Comment: its not shrinking into the header in my computer